# Webview navigation returning wrong url

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview that looks like this

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.loadUrl("https://myurl.com/");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivityWebView.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;

        }
    }
```

When i change my URL to google everything works great, i can navigate to different sites and everything works.

When I put in my URl it is supposed to link to myurl2, but when I click it the toast prints myurl instead and the page juts reloads (not helpful!).

Any idea as to how this could happen and where shouldOverrideUrlLoading gets its url from?

If i load myurl in a browser and the user clicks a button then it works correctly.

If i load myurl in a webview, but open a browser on links pressed, then when the link is pressed it opens myurl on in a broswer and if you click the button again it correctly opens myurl2 (super weird).

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing, can you just tell me which URL you want to open in your webview? myUrl1 or myUrl2 ?

Comment: unfortunately its  client privileged :( 

What do you find difficult to follow?  I open up one website my client owns that has a button that should navigate to a second website he owns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL is opening in Chrome properly, you should consider adding, `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` to your code and try again.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the loaded URL from

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // do your stuff here
}
});
```

Comment: yeh i can get the url, the problem is that it is serving the wrong url.  If I open the same website in a browser it serves the correct url

Comment: Are you opening in desktop browser or mobile browser? because URL may be different for mobile as well as desktop browser (due to screen compatible)

Comment: mobile, did you read the bottom of my opening thread?  

i think i have worked out the problem though, its cutting off all the parameters, is that expected?